# How to retrieve custom columnDefinition of Doctrine2 Entity?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, entitymanager, silex

I'm using **columnDefinition** syntax of Doctrine2 entity to implement ENUM column for my entity.

```
/**
 * @Column(type="string", columnDefinition="ENUM('active','finished','cancelled')",
 * options={"comment" = "Job status"})
 **/
protected $Status = 'active';
```

Now I'm trying to retrieve definition of this column to get list of possible field values. I've looked through **Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo** but haven't found any suitable method to get this data. Can anyone give me some glues?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD:** Question is exactly about "columnDefinition" approach. I do know about solution with custom doctrine ENUMType class, but it is not what I'm currently looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `$em->getClassMetadata('My\Entity')->getFieldMapping('my_property')`?

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer Bingo! =) That is it! I saw this method previously but was pretty sure it's intended for mapped fields, not for "plain" ones. 
Can you please make an answer of your comment so that I could assign the bounty. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to grab the info you want like this:

```
$metadata = $em->getClassMetadata('My\Entity');
$myPropertyMapping = $metadata->getFieldMapping('myProperty');
```

A "field" in Doctrine is a property of an "entity" that has mapping information, but is not an "association". In other words: if you've defined a `@Column` annotation in the docblock, it's a "field".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to fetch the metadata you could use the approach from solution2 suggested in the [documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/cookbook/mysql-enums.html#solution-2-defining-a-type). You could create a type for your enum. I have extended the abstract EnumType with the `getValues()` method and created your enum class `EnumJobStatusType` (note that the name property is the relevant type for your entity).

This way you can just call the following to get your values and by using constants for your values you have an easy and save way for setting your status:

```
<?php
// fetching the possible values
$enum = new \MyProject\DBAL\EnumJobStatusType();
$values = $enum->getValues();

//setting the active status
$job->setStatus(\MyProject\DBAL\EnumJobStatusType::ACTIVE);
```

Your entity class with custom type "enumjobstatus":

```
<?php
/** @Entity */
class Job
{
    /**
    * @Column(type="enumjobstatus")
    **/
    private $status;
}
```

The abstact enum type class with extended `getValues()` method:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\DBAL;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

abstract class EnumType extends Type
{
    protected $name;
    protected $values = array();

    public function getSqlDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        $values = array_map(function($val) { return "'".$val."'"; }, $this->values);

        return "ENUM(".implode(", ", $values).") COMMENT '(DC2Type:".$this->name.")'";
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if (!in_array($value, $this->values)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Invalid '".$this->name."' value.");
        }
        return $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getValues() {
        return $this->values;
    }
}
```

The job status enum type:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\DBAL;

class EnumJobStatusType extends EnumType
{
    const ACTIVE = 'active';
    const FINISHED = 'finished';
    const CANCELLED = 'cancelled';

    protected $name = 'enumjobstatus';
    protected $values = array(self::ACTIVE, self::FINISHED, self::CANCELLED);
}
```

**Note that you need to register your type with**

```
Type::addType('enumjobstatus', 'MyProject\DBAL\EnumJobStatusType');
```

Comment: I've already seen this solution and it even gonna work but for now I do really need to use "columnDefinition" approach. Thanks for answer but it is not what I was asking about.